# jQuery-CSV + Flot read data from csv file relative path

Tags: jquery, csv, flot, jquery-csv

I try to implement jQuery-CSV with flot.

There is a example how to open a file from harddisk and plot it as a graph. This works fine.

```
<div id=flot2 style="width:600px;height:300px;margin:0 auto;"></div>
<input id=fileInput type=file name=files[] multiple />
```

But in my case I do not want to open a file from harddisc - the .csv file is already opluaded into my html structure.

```
/data/test.csv f.e.
```

does someone know how to change the input to the path of the .csv file?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, please explain what you have tried and provide a code example (e.g. a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)).

Comment: And perhaps this [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) can help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a demo for that...

[Flot Demo](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/flot.html)

The file has to be loaded via an open file dialog. The sandbox protections prevent scripts from accessing the user's filesystem directly.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of jquery-csv.*